# How to use a Bash Script to move and rename files with grep

Tags: linux, shell-script, grep, rename

Hi I an FTP folder called Input where I get sent files which look something like this:

```
"Guide to Iceland _ Chen-ping Wang itinerary T-987654987.pdf"
"Guide to Iceland _ T-123654875 Chen-ping Wang itinerary.pdf"
```

Basicly the description of the file can be different but it always includes "T-" and some numbers.

I need to create a bash script that copies the file to the folder ../Output and renames the file so the "T-" and the numbers comes first, and then rest of the filename. 
Example: `"T-123654875 - Guide to Iceland _ Chen-ping Wang itinerary.pdf"`

I intended to use Grep to get the name right.
Searching for `(.+)(T-\d+)` and replacing it with `$2 - $1`

But I can't get it to work right.

Comment: Does your system have the perl-based `rename` / `prename` command?

Comment: I am running this on Macintosh and intended to use the move mv command to rename it.

Comment: What do your current efforts look like?

Answer (score 1):

`grep` alone and replace to me doesn't look like a usable combo.  How do you feel about `sed`?

```
$ ls *pdf
Guide to Iceland _ Chen-ping Wang itinerary T-987654987.pdf
Guide to Iceland _ T-123654875 Chen-ping Wang itinerary.pdf
```

And then a little for loop in `bash`:

```
$ for i in *pdf; do mv "$i" "$( echo $i |  sed -r  's/^(.*)(T-[0-9]{9})(.+)$/\2 - \1\3/'  )"; done
```

This iterates over all PDFs in the current directory; stores their name in `$i` for every iteration, echos the content through sed (and uses its output as the target of the `mv`). `sed` breaks up the file-name in three parts and rearranges these. I recommend replacing `mv` with `echo mv` for testing :)

Which gives us:

```
$ ls *pdf
T-123654875 - Guide to Iceland _  Chen-ping Wang itinerary.pdf
T-987654987 - Guide to Iceland _ Chen-ping Wang itinerary .pdf
```

Comment: Thank you @tink sed is deffenetly the tool I should be using. 
There where one fault with the code to have it run in bash in my case sed use "-E" in stead of "-r" for regular expression.

`$ for i in *pdf; do mv "$i" "$( echo $i |  sed -E  's/^(.*)(T-[0-9]{9})(.+)$/\2 - \1\3/'  )"; done` 

But I need help making changes to the code. 
I don't need to check if it is PDF and I use an app to run the script and it Use $1 to refer to the file being processed. 

Can you help me make the modification so it works.